# jQuery check if element has a class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to check to see if an HTML element has a class and if so, then run a function with jQuery. My code only works if an element doesn't have multiple classes. I believe I need to use the `.hasClass()` method, but I couldn't figure it out.

```
var pageClass = $("body").attr('class');
switch (pageClass) {
  case ("page1"):
    $('h1').html('heading1');
    break;
  case ("page2"):
     $('h1').html('heading2');
    break;
  default:
    $('h1').html('default');
}
```

fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/9o70dbzz/2/

Comment: Instead of switch statement use if else with hasClass()

Comment: what would you do if the `body` had all 3 classes? would you only want the first, or last, or append all together?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/hasClass <--- The documentation is right there, free of charge, ready for you to read it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be solved with selectors:

```
$('h1').html('default');
$('body.page1 h1').html('heading1');
$('body.page2 h1').html('heading2');
```

Answer (score 10):

Use the [.hasClass()](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/) function.

```
if($("body").hasClass("page1")){
  $("h1").html("heading1");
}
else if($("body").hasClass("page2"){
  $("h1").html("heading2");
}
else {
  $("h1").html("default");
}
```

Comment: is the only way is to use if else statement?

Comment: Using if/else with the "hasClass" function is the easiest way. Using a switch statement would be too convoluted in this scenario.

Comment: What Sonny says makes sense, as the code examples use multiple classes. The `.hasClass()` method is similar to `if (className.indexOf('page1') > -1) { ... }`. Neither one of those works well in a switch. However, you could use unique id attributes with a switch. Like: `<body id="page1">` or `<body id="page2">` & then use `switch($("body").attr("id")) {...}`. The reason is that only 1 value is passed into the switch with the id, rather than multiple values with the classes. So it's good to remember that switches work with single value keys & if/else statements work with multiple input keys.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it in such way....

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var element = $("body");

var classesCollection = {
    'page1': 'heading1',
    'page2': 'heading2'
};

for (var propertyName in classesCollection) {
    var propertyValue = classesCollection[propertyName];
    if (element.hasClass(propertyName)) element.html(propertyValue);
    else element.html('default');
}

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9o70dbzz/4/